# Adding a for loop within a variable declaration

Tags: javascript, loops

> Im having trouble looping through the array tabData and storing the new array into 'filteredData'

```
const filteredData = allData.filter(
            ({ class }) => tab === tabData[1].tab && class === tabData[1].label,
        );
```

> tabData contains the following  0:{Tab:1, Label:'firstTab'} 1:{Tab:2 , Label:'secondTab'} ... and so on

Comment: what does `allData` look like? If you're not using `Class` in your filter condition there is no need to destructure it.

Comment: Please read the documentation on how to correctly format a question in Stackoverflow. Describe what you are trying to do and what you want to achieve as well as describing your code.

Comment: The [`filter` callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Syntax) provides a second argument which is the current index of the iteration. So if tabData is the same size as allData just use that as the variable. Otherwise you would need to explain the relation between allData and tabData to better help

Comment: Where is `tabData[1]` coming from? Based on your code and the data you provided, there is no `tabData`.

Comment: tab data is an array that I currently have defined, im having trouble looping through it

Comment: Because you're trying to iterate through an array called `allData`.

Comment: I see `tabData` now. Where is `tab` coming from?

Comment: What is in `allData`? Hard to debug code that is missing stuff that we can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You cant use 'class' is reserved word.

2) I guess code should look like:

```
const filteredData = allData.filter(tab => tab.label === OTHER.label)
```

Where "OTHER.label" filtering for that label

Answer (score 0):

You’d better take a look at Array.prototype.filter ’doc

var newArray = arr.filter(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])

[see details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)